# printToPDF renders in tab size instead of actual window size

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, electron

My electron app has a print facility, which directly prints the content of my window. It uses Bootstrap for layouts. The electron window is rendered as expected, but while I print the content using `printToPDF` the generated PDF looks a screenshot of tab size. Have attached images for better understanding.

**Code Snippet:**

```
win.webContents.printToPDF({pageSize:"A4",printBackground: true}, (error, data) => {

    if (error) throw error

    fs.writeFile('print.pdf', data, (error) => {

        if (error) throw error

        console.log('Write PDF successfully.');
    });
});
```

In alternate, I have also tried for `window.print()` and it produces the same issue.

I need to print the screen as it was displayed in window.

**Expected (screenshot of electron window):**
[image]

**Actual (screenshot of generated PDF):**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Printing the entire window by getting access to it has worked for me.

```
  var childWindow = getWindow("My-Window-Name");

  childWindow.webContents.printToPDF({
     landscape: true
     }, function(err, data) {
     var dist = "";
     var dir = "";
     if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
     dir = "C:\\store\\" + serialNumber;

     if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
       fs.mkdirSync(dir);
     }
       dist = dir +  '\\' + serialNumber + '.pdf'
     } else {
       dir = __dirname + '/' + serialNumber;

     if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
       fs.mkdirSync(dir);
     }
       dist = dir +  '/' + serialNumber + '.pdf'
     }

     fs.writeFile(dist, data, function(err) {
       if(err) console.log('genearte pdf error', err)
     })
     })

// code to get reference to window
   function getWindow(windowName) {
     var windowArray = BrowserWindow.getAllWindows();
     console.log(windowArray[0].getTitle());
     for (var i = 0; i < windowArray.length; i++) {
       if (windowArray[i].getTitle() == windowName) {
         return windowArray[i];
       }
     }
   return null;
   }
```